# Generating correct swagger spec for Java LocalDateTime

Tags: java, swagger

I am trying to get swagger spec(yaml) from Java code using Swagger Annotations in a spring boot application. I annotate the models and then run the springboot app and then get the spec from http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs.

My Model Looks like below  :

```
package com.indiana.core;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;

@lombok.ToString
@lombok.Getter
@lombok.Setter
public class SampleClass{

        @JsonProperty(value = "birth_date_time")
    private LocalDateTime birthDateTime;
....
}'
```

I want to create correct swagger yaml speck for this. I expect the below when I access swagger UI which provides the yaml automatically .

Note that dateOfBirth is a Java 8 LocalDateTime class . But as per swagger spec(https://swagger.io/specification/ look for Data Types Sections ) the Date in yaml should be type : 'string' and format: date-time.

```
 'SampleClass:
    properties:
      dateOfBirth:
        type: string
        format: date-time'
```

What I am getting now  :

It looks like swagger is building a detailed definition LocalDateTime, which is not I am looking for .

```
'"definitions": {
        "LocalDateTime": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "chronology": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Chronology"
                },
                "dayOfMonth": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                },
                "dayOfWeek": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY", "SUNDAY"]
                },
                "dayOfYear": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                },
                "hour": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                },
                "minute": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                },
                "month": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"]
                },
                "monthValue": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                },
                "nano": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                },
                "second": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                },
                "year": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                }
            }
        },
```

I have tried with

```
'A. @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "java.lang.String", example = "17-03-2019 22:18:59", notes = "Birthdaytime desc")
B. @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss")'
```

Out these for A , the element is defined as string only in the yaml , the 'format: date-time' is missing like below .

```
 SampleClass:
    properties:
      dateOfBirth:
        type: string
```

What tweaking is needed to create aperfect swegger for this ?
I need this

```
 SampleClass:
    properties:
      dateOfBirth:
        type: string
        format: date-time .
```

Answer (score 3):

Just put below annotation on your LocalDateTime field to format datetime in swagger definition:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", shape = Shape.STRING)
@ApiModelProperty(required = true, example = "2021-08-20T00:00:00")
```